# Playing audio after another has finished with Js

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner and have some problems with this issue:

I want to play a list/array of audio files. The list of audio is dependent on the users textinput. The next audio should be playing only if the other has ended.

I've tried to do this with a for-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i< textinput.length; i++){

        switch(textinput[i]){

            case 'a': playMusic('a');
                        break;
            case 'b' : playMusic('b');
                        break;
            case 'c' : playMusic('c');
                        break;
            default: playMusic('d');

        }
    }
```

Of course it plays all audio files at the same time.

So I've tried to add a listener with 'onended' but I'm always ending with an endless loop...Could someone help me?

Comment: What is the HTML you are using? Are you using an `audio` element?

Comment: Yes, I am using the audio element, for example: 
`<audio id="a" preload="auto">
    <source src="src/audio/a.mp3"/>
</audio>`

Comment: You can simply check the property `element.ended` to see if it has completed.

Comment: I've added an answer for you that I think will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of checking the status of an `HTMLAudioElement` would be as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio id='audio' autoplay controls src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio>
        <select id='select'>
            <option value="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3" >Roar!</option>
            <option value="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-15.mp3" >Sample song</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            audio.onended = function () {
                this.setAttribute('src', document.getElementById('select').value);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that you can't start playing audio via the script without the user's interaction. You will always need to use an event to trigger an audio to be played (this is due to security reasons).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, I'll try :-)

Comment: @ingita if my answer helped you, feel free to give it an upvote :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have an error with your logic. 
Why would you keep the memory busy with a "who knows when it is going to end" loop?
Your task is clear, playing a set of sounds in order, like a playlist.

For this you have events. An audio tag provides you [certain events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) like "playing", "seeking" or "ended". You can use these events for a chain trigger.

Keep the index of current playing audio, on each "ended" event update it with the next one if there is no new one just do nothing.

```
audioObject.addEventListener('ended',function(e){
    current++; //Your current index
    if(current < totalAudioCount){ //Check if there is other audio.
      playMusic(audioIndex[current])
    }
});
```

I'm sure you can find tons of tutorials for this subject. Please before asking questions do some research, if the things you have tried won't work, explain it here then ask your question.

P.S. Never trust input from the user, you have to check are the values are in the expected format, are they valid?